# Making private changes to Three20

Tags: git, three20

I've made some private changes to the public Three20 libraries.  Three20 will now work with semi-trusted SSL certs.  Custom views are now working for headers in grouped table views.  Custom chrome is now allowed on the photocontroller, and the network performance was tuned for image loading over 3G.  Finally, a display bug that would cause textfield cells to disappear from a TTTableViewController was fixed.

Unfortunately, I have sinned. I didn't make a new branch before doing this.

```
%git status

# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 3 commits.
# nothing to commit (working directory clean)

%git log

commit a6ab33d74dd92787a0f7f2b7aa25911aff06a709
Author: Scott Penberthy <scott@nhighland.com>
Date:   Mon Sep 27 15:35:46 2010 -0400

    Add appropriate method headers to expose custom views, custom chrome

commit 9b65760c0ab9f0b7d576d657ab6fd42e8446ed81
Author: Scott Penberthy <scott@nhighland.com>
Date:   Tue Sep 21 14:36:38 2010 -0400

    Updated to 4.1, allowed custom table header views in a grouped table

commit 52f95dc5d0e1a7f51d0cf992859f90d3ee212783
Author: Scott Penberthy <scott@nhighland.com>
Date:   Sun Aug 29 10:18:52 2010 -0400

    Fix display bug in TTableControlCell.  Tune network.  Fix SSL bug with bad cert.
```

Is there an easy way to create a diff from these three commits?  I'd like to offer these to Three20 and also let others use the changes.  What's the best way to bundle just my local changes?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `git-format-patch` **[man page](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html)**.  That will create patch files (text) that you can send to them and they can easily apply.  In your case, probably...

`git format-patch 52f95dc5..`